# ask breed agent id to do something

Tags: netlogo

Here is the problem. There are many type of turtles, persons, stairs, elevators, and escalators.

I also have data, the data is the traced location of persons at different tick time. I want to put the t-list, x-list and y-list under different persons by agent-id variable. The problem is, if there is only one turtle, which is person, the code of following is work.

```
globals [ num-agent t-list x-list y-list agent-id ]
to-report read-trace[ file ]
 .....
end
to setup
let listInput read-trace "filename.csv"
let param item 0 listInput
set num-agent item 0 param
set listInput but-first listInput

 create-turtles num-agent [
  set t-list []
  set x-list []
  set y-list []
  set size 2
  set shape "person"
  set speed random-float (1)
]

foreach listInput [
 let t item 0 ?
 set agent-id item 1 ? - 1
 let locationid item 2 ?
 let x item 3 ?
 let y item 4 ?

ask turtles agent-id [
  set t-list sentence t-list t
  ; scale x-y to fit in the world size (100 x 100)
  set x-list sentence x-list x 
  set y-list sentence y-list y 
  ]
]
end
```

But, if breed other types of agent, I only want to put t-list, x-list and y-list under turtle-person by different agent-id, it is not work!

```
globals [ num-agent t-list x-list y-list agent-id ]
breed [ persons person ]
breed [ stairs stair ]
breed [ elevators elevator]
breed [ escalators escalator ]
breed [ nextlocations nextlocation ]
to-report read-trace[ file ]
 .....
end
to setup
let listInput read-trace "filename.csv"
let param item 0 listInput
set num-agent item 0 param
set listInput but-first listInput

 create-persons num-agent [
  set t-list []
  set x-list []
  set y-list []
  set size 2
  set shape "person"
  set speed random-float (1)
]

foreach listInput [
 let t item 0 ?
 set agent-id item 1 ? - 1
 let locationid item 2 ?
 let x item 3 ?
 let y item 4 ?

ask persons agent-id [
  set t-list sentence t-list t
  ; scale x-y to fit in the world size (100 x 100)
  set x-list sentence x-list x 
  set y-list sentence y-list y 
  ]
]
end
```

The problem comes of ask person agent-id!
Anyone can help me? Thank you very much! Many many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to access agents by number, but generally speaking, you should not do that.  Here the problem arises for three reasons.

1. Turtles are created with an id number, which is their `who` number, which is unique among *all* turtles (not just within a breed)
2. When you ask a single turtle, you must use the singular (`turtle` not `turtles`, or here `person` not `persons`.
3. Wnen you ask a single turtle this way, you must use its `who` number. You cannot use some other identifier (such as `agent-id`), unless you are sure that corresponds to its `who` number.

So if you copied and pasted your code, `ask persons agent-id` fails for a variety of reasons: you are trying to a. `ask persons`, which is all persons, and b. ask by a single number, `agent-id`, which can at best identify one turtle, and c. use the value of `agent-id` which may or may not correspond to the `who` number of a `person` (depending on whether or not you create persons before any other turtles).  In principle you could fix all this by making sure that `persons` are all created before any other turtles and changing to `ask person agent-id`.  But again, manipulating on `who` numbers is usually unwise.

Assuming you do not ever kill off or create more turtles, you could introduce a global `sorted-persons` and set it to the list `sort persons` right after you create your persons.  Then you could `ask item agent-id sorted-persons` to do whatever you want, if you really feel you must access them by `agent-id`.

Comment: Thank you so much! You did help me and gave me a hint of how to solve it. I did need the agent-id to clarify whether the agent still in the environment or not. Thanks!!